# Iterating through a struts2 list at JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2

I have a list which i populate by a java method when I load a JSP page. Struts2 allows me to use that list in the  fashion. The list contains stuff such as-

```
#<String Name,String Group>
```

Now, there can be instances of a name having many groups. The list can be like-

```
<Josh,A>
<Josh,B>
<Raj,A>
<Raj,B>
<Raj,C>
```

There is a form which I am using of which the select tag is used to first select the name, and then the groups for the name.

I need to uniquely provide the list (ie, the drop down selector should only have one instance of the names), and then once i select a name, i should be able to select the relevant group for the name. So say if i select "Josh", the next drop down should then be populated with "A,B"- the groups "Josh" falls into.

The way I have been thinking of implementing this is-
Get this list from the server to the client (Struts2), Process this list using javascript- to get another unique list of names, and then when a name is selected, process the list (which has been fetched) with that name ('for' iterate over the list, and find the groups).

Is this possible? What is the way I can use the list variable to be processed at the client side (using javascript functions)?

Thanks.

Comment: There are any number of ways to implement this, including building all the JS during initial page load, or using Ajax to dynamically build the options for each dependent list. What makes the most sense depends on your requirements.

Comment: I have been thinking on the first. (I bring the entire database table out with the page load in the "list"). I hope that is what you were asking. I'm new to JSP/Struts2, have been a C++ guy

Comment: Then you may need to provide further info regarding what the actual question is. Also, there are a lot of examples of dependent select/option implementations on the web--any of them might be enough to get you going :)

Comment: I do have an idea of dependent select. I don't know if i can use a list/array variable which i have got from the server (courtesy struts2)- and process it at the client.

Comment: Again--the HTML/JS is built on the server side, using the lists/whatever of your data. Once the HTML/JS is built, there's no "processing" to be done, just creating/filling/hiding/showing/whatever the dependent lists--which of those you do depends on how you're implementing it.

Comment: Thanks Dave, that last comment got me thinking. I'll be back with what I find.

Comment: So the way i finally decided to do this is to get everything at the javascript in the form of arrays, and populate the fields based on selection. Thanks.